# Distinct record select for records that contain only one email address

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create a report that pulls over records that contain only email address per record. Can anyone help me with this? I am not very experienced with Crystal so any help would be really appreciated. I have tried using count and max but nothing has worked for me so far. Thanks, Cindy

Comment: Can you post some sample data ?

Answer (score 0):

To pull distinct records

```
go to  ---> Database ---> Select distinct Records
```

If this is not your are looking for then provide more detail about your problem

Answer (score 0):

First You have to create a stored procedure that retrieves the distinct records that you need.
second you have to create a crystal report and set datasource location or select your procedure from Database Expert (Create New Connection -> select your connection type-> insert credentials to open the connection-> select your procedure)
Third from Field Explorer your Procedure will appear and the columns of your query all you have to do from here is to work on the layout(Design) and drag & drop your required field.